# How to edit a CSV file row by row in Python without using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file and when I read it by importing the CSV library I get as the output:

```
['exam', 'id_student', 'grade']`
['maths', '573834', '7']`
['biology', '573834', '8']`
['biology', '578833', '4']
['english', '581775', '7']`
# goes on...
```

I need to edit it by creating a 4th column called 'Passed' with two possible values: True or False depending on whether the grade of the row is >= 7 (True) or not (False), and then count how many times each student passed an exam.
If it's not possible to edit the CSV file that way, I would need to just read the CSV file and then create a dictionary of lists with the following output:

```
dict = {'id_student':[573834, 578833, 581775], 'passed_count': [2,0,1]}
# goes on...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using importing csv as pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

And then use:

```
data['passed']=(data['grades']>=7).astype(bool)
```

And then save dataframe to csv as:

```
data.to_csv('final.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: If your query is satisfied , dont forget to upvote. Else let me know in comments.

Comment: You was asked not to use pandas.

Comment: Read the title please

Answer (score 1):

It is totally possible to "edit" CSV.

Assuming you have a file `students.csv` with the following content:

```
exam,id_student,grade
maths,573834,7
biology,573834,8
biology,578833,4
english,581775,7
```

Iterate over input rows, augment the field list of each row with an additional item, and save it back to another CSV:

```py
import csv

with open('students.csv', 'r', newline='') as source, open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as result:
    csvreader = csv.reader(source)
    csvwriter = csv.writer(result)

    # Deal with the header
    header = next(csvreader)
    header.append('Passed')
    csvwriter.writerow(header)

    # Process data rows
    for row in csvreader:
        row.append(str(int(row[2]) >= 7))
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Now `result.csv` has the content you need.

If you need to replace the original content, use [os.remove()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) and [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) to do that:

```py
import os

os.remove('students.csv')
os.rename('result.csv', 'students.csv')
```

As for counting, it might be an independent thing, you don't need to modify CSV for that:

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict


with open('students.csv', 'r', newline='') as source:
    csvreader = csv.reader(source)
    next(csvreader)     # Skip header

    stats = defaultdict(int)
    for row in csvreader:
        if int(row[2]) >= 7:
            stats[row[1]] += 1

print(stats)
```

You can include counting into the code above and have both pieces in one place. `defaultdict` (`stats`) has the same interface as `dict` if you need to access that.

Comment: `source_rows` is not defined, plus the code doesn't throw the output expected

Comment: @Hernan, augmented the answer.